# Having a problem launching Matlab 2010 in Ubuntu related to libXp.so.6

Tags: matlab

I did not have any problem opening Matlab2010 in Ubuntu by typing `matlab2010`, but now if I type the same thing, I get:

> error while loading shared libraries: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am not sure that this is because of updating to new version (Ubuntu 15.10, 64-bit) but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB from 2010 is quite old; modern versions of MATLAB (r2015b) no longer use `libXp.so`.

```
$ pwd
/opt/Attic/matlab.r2010b
$ cd bin/glnxa64/
$ ldd MATLAB | grep -i libxp
        libXpm.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libXpm.so.4 (0x00000032e7400000)
        libXp.so.6 => not found
$ cd /opt/matlab.r2015b/bin/glnxa64/
$ ldd MATLAB | grep -i libxp
$
```

You'll need to either update MATLAB to a current version, or figure out a way to port the old X.Org X11 libXp runtime library to run on Ubuntu 15, or to perhaps run MATLAB under a virt running an older OS version.